# DataGrid Scroll no appearing in auto grid height

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, datagrid, scroll

I have been having problems with the Grid, Row Height being auto, Grid splitter, and data grid.

So in detail:

I have in design 3 rows in the following order
- Property Grid
- Grid Splitter
- Data Grid

as follows:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="250"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto" MaxHeight="550"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<pg:PropertyGrid Name="_propertyGrid" />

<GridSplitter Height="4" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0"
     Panel.ZIndex="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment" 
     ResizeDirection="Rows" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
</GridSplitter>

<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Name="_dgDataValues" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
     CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
</DataGrid>
```

The problem I have, is my DataValues data grid DOES NOT show the scroll bar initially, but if I adjust the GRID SPLITTER, the school will appear, is there a way to make it so that when it loads up, without moving the splitter, show the scroll IF NECESSARY???

Thanks and Regards,
Kev

Comment: Have you tried `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=Auto`?

Comment: Or VerticalScroll = Visiable.  What is in row 0?

Comment: I have tried both ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarvisibility = Auto, and VerticalScroll = Visible.

The first does not work, and I do not want to always show the scroll bar for the latter.

The problem is I have to have "auto" for the grid row Definition, the auto is screwing it up, but i need it in order to have the grid splitter work